# kafka on pod: working with java but not python - certificate error

Tags: python, java, ssl, apache-kafka

I'm trying to consume and later on produce kafka messages on a pod but I'm having some problems with the certificates...
I tried this bash script that runs java on the pod:

```
$ wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.2.0/kafka_2.13-3.2.0.tgz
$ tar -xzf kafka_2.13-3.2.0.tgz
$ cd kafka_2.13-3.2.0/bin
$ echo "security.protocol=SSL" >  my.properties

$ ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic pingone_fraud --bootstrap-server <host>:9093 --command-config my.properties 
# output: 
Topic: <topic>  PartitionCount: 8   ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: cleanup.policy=delete,segment.bytes=262144000,retention.bytes=53687063712

Topic: <topic>  Partition: 0    Leader: 204 Replicas: 204,203,205   Isr: 204,203,205
.
.
.
```

and as you can see from the output it worked without a problem! But when I'm trying to consume my messages using my python code:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(<topic>,
                         security_protocol='SSL',
                         ssl_cafile='/keys/CARoot.pem',
                         request_timeout_ms=_request_timeout_ms,
                         connections_max_idle_ms=_connections_max_idle_ms,
                         bootstrap_servers='<host>:9093',
                         group_id='fraud',
                         auto_offset_reset=_auto_offset_reset,
                         max_poll_interval_ms=_max_poll_interval_ms,
                         session_timeout_ms=_session_timeout_ms,
                         max_poll_records=_max_poll_records)
print(f'************* {consumer.topics()}')
```

I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/kafka_consumer.py", line 30, in <module>
    max_poll_records=_max_poll_records)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 354, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 908, in check_version
    version = conn.check_version(timeout=remaining, strict=strict, topics=list(self.config['bootstrap_topics_filter']))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 1171, in check_version
    if not self.connect_blocking(timeout_at - time.time()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 333, in connect_blocking
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 422, in connect
    if self._try_handshake():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 501, in _try_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

Now about the certificate I use, in keytool I have a certificate that I extract from vault and I exported it using keytool so that I could use it with my python code:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore /opt/java/lib/security/cacerts -alias vault-us -rfc -file /keys/CARoot.pem
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why my python code does not work because a certificate error while I'm using the same certificate...

Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like kafka does some weird ssl context stuff behind the scenes.
I solved it by creating my own ssl context and giving it to my kafka consumer:

```
def create_ssl_context():
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations('/keys/vault_us.pem')
    return ssl_context


consumer = KafkaConsumer(_topic_name,
                         ssl_context=create_ssl_context(),
                         security_protocol='SSL',
                         request_timeout_ms=_request_timeout_ms,
                         connections_max_idle_ms=_connections_max_idle_ms,
                         bootstrap_servers='<host>:9093',
                         group_id='fraud',
                         auto_offset_reset=_auto_offset_reset,
                         max_poll_interval_ms=_max_poll_interval_ms,
                         session_timeout_ms=_session_timeout_ms,
                         max_poll_records=_max_poll_records)
```